# Am I contributing to the site?

Tags: discussion

I'm a novice user, I've been playing with the RPi a lot lately but I haven't seen any questions that I can answer.

My only contribution so far is to up vote questions and comments I think are useful.

Is this helpful to a site in beta?

I will of course be asking questions when they crop up as well!

Am I helping the site at all?

Comment: You're doing well. Keep it up :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Yes!

Don't worry if you can't answer questions, just providing questions to be answered, when you have them, is often the thing a lot of betas struggle with most.

A lot of betas have an initial rush then a bit of a slump, especially on questions - so people who can post a steady stream of good, relevant questions are much appreciated, and very much needed. It's not all about just rushing to provide the best answers. If there were no questions, there wouldn't be any!

Another point worth mentioning, I think most people here are very aware of the fact that the Raspberry Pi will probably attract beginners in a number of areas, so even very basic questions would still be welcome as I see it.

Answer (score 3):

Yup!

SE sites are about Qs, As, and being able to find good ones easily - voting is very useful!

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Other things you can do:

- Suggest edits to existing questions & answers.
  You gain +2 rep for each edit that is approved by the author.
- Flag spam and "me too" answers for moderation (you don't get rep for this, but you can get the [deputy](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/badges/70/deputy) and [marshal](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/badges/76/marshal) badges.)